# Customize message Gitlab notifications to Google chat Integration

Tags: gitlab, bots, integration, customization, google-chat

Actually I've integrated Gitlab notifications to Google chat. Is it possible to change the automatic Gitlab notifications on Google Chat.

For example, if there's a merge request, we get the following message from the Webhook:

> 7d5cfbd2: Gitlab User (gitlab.user) opened merge request !123 Resolve FOO-123 in Group / Project

And when the pipeline has failed, the message is:

> Pipeline #482890700 has failed in 09:25

So, the form of the message should be different. Something like this:

> @User your pipeline has failed , {link-pipeline}.